# What style of icing is this please?

Tags: icing

[image]

I want to make this cake with this style of icing and I can't find anything on it. Can someone please tell me what style it is or give me a link to a tutorial? I'm more interested in the icing on the cake, it is a dripping effect that I like. I'm unsure of what icing was used and how to get that look.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about the sculptural elements, the icing used to create those is called fondant.

The name fondant comes from the french for melting.  It has a consistency somewhere between play dough and tootsie rolls.

Here is a [good tutorial](http://honestcooking.com/making-your-own-fondant/) on making fondant.  It can also be purchased.  You can find millions of tutorials on how to work with fondant.  The tutorials tend to focus and what is being sculpted.  If you are looking for a very simple how-to for working with fondant [this is a good tutorial](http://bakingdom.com/2010/09/tutorial-tuesday-how-to-make-beautiful-fondant-cakes.html)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fondant_icing

Answer (score 0):

The frosting on the cake itself looks to me like [Seven Minute Frosting](https://www.google.com/search?q=seven+minute+icing&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=pTxnU9P-B8HboATTxoCgAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CI8BELAE&biw=1536&bih=738), also known as a Swiss Meringue. Here's a highly rated [recipe](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/seven-minute-frosting-recipe) from a reliable site.

It also could be [Marshmallow Icing](https://www.google.com/search?q=marshmallow+frosting&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=BD5nU6OMJ4_9oASAqYG4Dg&ved=0CE8QsAQ&biw=1536&bih=738), which is kind of a "cheater" method to get similar results to the Seven Minute Frosting. Here's a [recipe](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/super-easy-marshmallow-icing-recipe) from the same site.